# DD-WRT Security & Updates

Tags: router, firmware

In [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49350/is-dd-wrt-generally-more-secure-than-manufacturers-firmware) stackexchange question regarding the choice of router firmware the most upvoted answer states that security of an router is essentially determined by the frequency of shipped updates (*assuming a safe config*).

With this information I went to the dd-wrt website and queried the [router firmware database](https://secure.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database) for my pretty old Linksys WRT610N. There, the last firmware release was in August 2010, 6 years ago. I guess that is fairly unsecure to use.

Why are there no newer firmware versions, or updates to DD-WRT? Is there any other way to secure a router this old?

Comment: Likely because Linksys has developed something newer, with better hardware. After some time, software and hardware companies don't want to support their older stuff; they would rather their customers go to something new. And, honestly, in today's world, you should probably get an upgrade anyway; technology of today is much more powerful, reliable, and secure.

Comment: "Why are there no newer firmware versions, or updates to DD-WRT?" - The developers of DD-WRT have determined the changes to the kernel make it incompatible with your router and/or none of them have bothered to test the current version against your router because it is more then 6 years old.  "Is there any other way to secure a router this old?" - Who says its insecure?  Just because the kernel hasn't been updated does not automatically mean it is insecure.  Additionally there is nothing preventing you from downloading the source, fixing the security problems, and using that build instead.